# Problema al retornar un valor de tipo char en C

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código en lenguaje `C`, el cual trata de leer un archivo:

- Archivo `.txt` :

```c
156.23.54.45 255.255.0.0
31.13.65.36 255.255.192.0
```

El primer string lo almaceno en la variable `char ip[16]`, la cual luego comparo usando la función `strcmp` para comprobar si existe el "ip" en el archivo que leo previamente. Esto lo hace perfecto, el problema es a la hora de retornar la otra variable llamada `mask`. Si ejecuto el `printf` si muestra lo que necesito, pero a la hora de tratar de retornar el valor, este no muestra nada a la hora de compilar (compila sin errores por cierto)

- Código en `C`:

```
char redes(){
    FILE * archivo = fopen( "directorios.txt", "rb" ); 

    if( archivo == NULL) {
        perror( "Error en la apertura del archivo" );
        exit(1);
    }

    char ip[16];
    char mask[16];

    while( 1 ) {
        fscanf( archivo, "%s%s", ip, mask );

        if( feof( archivo ) != 0 ) {
            break;
        }

        if(strcmp(ip, "31.13.65.36") == 0){
//          printf("La mascara es %s", mask);
            return *mask;
        }
    }   

    fclose( archivo );
}

int main(){
    char mascara = redes();

    printf("%s", mascara);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicionalmente a los explicado en [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326847/19610) de [Juan Carlos Guibovich](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/152765/) , **NO DEBES** retornar `mask`.

`mask` es una variable automática. Su tiempo de vida está limitado al tiempo que transcurre **dentro** de tu función `redes( )`. Lo mas probable es que el compilador te muestre un *aviso* (*warning*) al compilar tu código.

Al hacerlo como lo haces, devolverás un puntero a una zona de memoria que puede o no contener lo que esperas. Es un comportamiento indefinido: igual todo funciona ... o igual obtienes un montón de caracteres basura.

Normalmente, se usaría memoria dinámica para hacer lo que pretendes (ver [`malloc( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), [`calloc( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc), [`realloc( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) y [`free( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free)).

También pueden usarse variables con almacenamiento estático. Esta solución tiene ciertos *problemillas* y una ventaja: **no usa memoria dinámica**.

Mirando tu código, una posible solución sería utilizar una variable como *buffer* persistente, de forma que se rellene la primera vez que llames a tu función, para, en veces sucesivas, no necesitar volver a leer del archivo, sino devolver directamente lo que ya tenemos almacenado:

```
const char *redes( ) {
  static char mask[16] = { 0 };

  if( !( mask[0] ) ) {
    // Primera vez. Leemos el archivo.
    FILE * archivo = fopen( "directorios.txt", "rb" );

    if( !archivo ) {
      perror( "Error en la apertura del archivo" );
      exit( 1 );
    }

    char ip[16];

    while( 1 ) {
      fscanf( archivo, "%s%s", ip, mask );

      if( feof( archivo ) != 0 ) {
        break;
      }

      if( !strcmp( ip, "31.13.65.36" ) ) {
        break;
      }
    }   

    fclose( archivo );
  }

  // Los datos ya están en la variable, bien porque los acabamos de leer,
  // bien porque estaban ahí de llamadas anteriores.
  return mask;
}

int main(){
  const char *mascara = redes( );

  printf( "%s", mascara );

  return 0;
}
```

Con este código, puedes llamar a tu función `redes( )` **todas las veces que quieras**. La lectura del archivo se realizará **únicamente la primera vez**.

Comment: Tienes razón,  en mi respuesta no consideré ese pequeño pero significativamente importante detalle. No debe devolver `mask` de la forma como esta declarada. Agregaré una nota haciendo referencia a tu observación.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que mask es un arreglo de 16  caracteres, por lo tanto, el  nombre en sí ya es un puntero. Ahora tu puedes acceder a los valores  utilizando la notación de puntero o arreglo. Por ejemplo: el primer elemento de mask puedes referenciarlo como mask[0] o *mask, al segundo como mask[1] o *(mask+1).

Por lo anterior, si quieres devolver la máscara de 16 tienes que devolver un puntero  o un arreglo . Eso lo puedes hacer cambiando el tipo de dato de la función redes:

```c
char* redes() {

     return mask;
}
```

y en main cambiar:

```c
char*  máscara = redes();
```

Si te das cuenta en el print tu  utilizas mask a secas por eso te saca la máscara completa. Ya cuando regresa , solo regresa el primer byte

---

**EDICION:** . La declaración de la variable `mask` tambien debe cambiarse. Ver respuesta de `@Trauma`.